# How to get the default Ubuntu graphic  driver for 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, resolution

I recently installed Nvidia graphic driver `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.43.run` 
downloaded from Nvidia official website that meet my graphic card GFroce GT 540M.

However, I got worse graphic on my display resolution changed to 640x640 CRT mode.
My  laptop is 1366x768.

May I get a better graphic than the default install? Or Ubuntu default install graphic is best?

Please help me to get the default Ubuntu graphic driver that is installed together with system installation.

Answer (score 2):

First of all remove the drivers installed with the .run running

```
sudo NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-304.43.run --uninstall
```

Then refer to the following guide to understand how to install nvidia drivers correctly.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Answer (score 0):

It't not that simple, cause there are many garbage files remaining still there and sometimes these files can cause problems. If you would like to install 304.43 or go back to Nouveau (open source) drivers, I would recommend you to use my script:

http://ubuntuxtreme.com/howto/how-to-install-nvidia-304-43-with-one-click/

Comment: Can you please post the steps here? It's preferable to just including a link.